# File becomes directory after rpm extraction using rpm2cpio

Tags: linux, rpm, cpio

I am extracting a rpm package on RHEL-6.4. I am using rpm2cpio command as below:

```
rpm2cpio package-name.rpm | cpio -u -i -d ---quiet 2>&1
```

The above command runs in fakeroot v1.12.4 environment. (cpio (GNU cpio) 2.10) After execution of above command if I check file tpye using `file` command it shows file as Directory.

I checked content of rpm using

```
rpm -qlpv package-name.rpm
```

It shows all files as file and directory as directory.

However, I noticed if i `unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and then check filetype using `file` command, it shows all data same as `rpm -qlp`.

LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set to

```
/opt/tools/wh/dtd/RHE-5/fakeroot/1.12.4/lib64/libfakeroot
```

why file is marked as directory when `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the rpm2cpio extract the archive including directory structure. So 
 /usr/bin/foo from archive becomes:

```
d /usr
d   /bin/
f      foo
```

So usr is indeed directory. But /usr/bin/foo is file (and it indeed is file on my workstation). Of course if you have LD_LIBRARY_PATH set something (and you did not shared to what) then it can point to directory which modify ANY system libraries and ANY system call. So the result can be ANYTHING. And it is hard to tell without knowing you local setup.

Note 1: you can call rpmdev-extract from rpmdevtools package. It is more comfortable.

Note 2: I do not see anything like `--queryformat perms` in supported options, but you can you `-qlpv`.

Comment: Agreed with -qlpv. I tried both --qf perms and -qlpv, by mistake I placed perms.

Comment: rpmdev-extract is not available on red hat, so couldn't try with it.

Comment: It is part of rpmdevtools package which *is* part of RHEL/Centos. See http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/rpmdevtools-7.5-2.el6.noarch.rpm

Comment: I have tested with fakeroot v1.20.2. It solved the issue. Can I answer my question?